# descending chain of non-finitely generated ideals

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (not necessarily with unity) such that $ab\ne 0,\forall a,b\in R\setminus\{0\}$. If every descending chain of non-finitely generated ideals of $R$ terminate, then is it true that every ascending chain of ideals in $R$ terminates ?

Comment: What is your definition for a Noetherian ring without identity anyway? ACC ? Finite generation of ideals? I thought I remember that these two things are no longer equivalent in that context.

Comment: @rschwieb: please see the edit

Comment: As rschweib has pointed out, this question as stated sounds kind of silly: if the conclusion that $R$ is Noetherian is to be true, then the premise must have actually been true only vacuously, since there can't have been any non-finitely generated ideals at all.  A rather more natural way to state the question is to take the contrapositive: if $R$ is non-Noetherian, must there exist a non-terminating descending chain of non-finitely generated ideals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  As a hint, if $I\subseteq R$ is any non-finitely generated ideal, consider the descending chain $$I\supseteq aI\supseteq a^2I\supseteq a^3I\supseteq\dots$$ for an appropriately chosen $a\in R$.

A full proof is hidden below.

> Let $a\in I$ be any nonzero element.  Then $I\neq aI$, since otherwise $a$ would generate $I$ as an ideal.  Thus $I\supset aI$, and it follows that all the other inclusions in the chain above are also strict, since they are obtained from $I\supset aI$ by multiplication by $a$ and multiplication by $a$ is injective.  Moreover, since multiplication by $a$ gives isomorphisms of $R$-modules $I\cong aI\cong a^2I\cong\dots$, all of these ideas are non-finitely generated.
>
>  So, this proves that if there exists a non-finitely generated ideal of $R$, then there exists a non-terminating infinite descending chain of such ideals.  This is exactly the contrapositive of your statement.

Comment: Does the claim remain true if no zero divisor condition is dropped ?

Comment: Hello ... are you there ...?

Answer (score 0):

At first I wondered if you didn’t mean the ACC, but then I saw it doesn’t seem to make a difference. Even considering this for rings with unity, the statement becomes silly.

If $R$ has even one non-finitely-generated ideal, it isn’t Noetherian.

If it is a ring with a nonempty chain of such ideals, then it has such an ideal.

So, this proposition could only hold in a ring with no non-finitely-generated ideals at all, whence it *is* Noetherian. But it is silly to characterize a ring property tautologically in terms of empty collections.

Comment: by "Noetherian" , I mean every ascending chain of ideals terminate ... I'm sorry to say that I quite don't understand what you are saying here ....

Comment: The statement is kind of silly, but it is still far from trivial.  It is effectively asking whether if there exists a non-finitely generated ideal, there must exist a non-terminating descending chain of such ideals.  This isn't obvious at all.

Comment: In other words, the phrasing of the question is silly, but it real meaning is an interesting question that is not silly at all.

Comment: @EricWofsey can you rephrase it to remove the silliness and show its interest?

Comment: Well, it is not clear to me that OP is aware that their statement is equivalent to my less silly version, so I don't want to make an edit which they would consider to be a nontrivial change to the question.

Comment: @EricWofsey I just meant in a comment. That is a pretty interesting proof of the contrapositive, but it still seems like a hollow proposition. Sort of in the same way that proof that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.  But yes I now agree it sounds better the way you said it.  Although it is still unsatisfying the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Wofsey has already answered the question affirmatively for integral domains. user521337 then modified the original question (in the comments to Wofsey's answer) to ask what happens when the ring is allowed to have nontrivial zero divisors. In this situation the answer is negative. One can derive this from [this answer.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304149) This link will take you to a description of a unital, commutative, local ring with exactly one nonfinitely generated ideal. Such a ring has no infinite descending chain of nonfinitely generated ideals, but must have an infinite ascending chain of ideals.